# Xcode 6: parse online calendar

Tags: objective-c, xcode, calendar

I am currently creating an app, in which the user is able to book devices (which are provided by a json file) for a certain time period (start date - end date). I was planning to use a online calendar, such as http://30boxes.com/welcome.php to check if the requested device is currently in use by another user at this period of time.

What might be the best strategy to parse that online calendar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just noticed this website has an API, which makes it super-easy to set and get the calendar data. I feel stupid right now: http://30boxes.com/api/